# Having problems with returning a value from a helper method

Tags: java

I'm new to coding and was assigned a project where I have to create a calculator. Right now I'm trying to turn all mixed number a regular number into proper/improper fractions but I cant get my program to return anything but what the user says. In the project the user can only put <number> <operator> <number>

```
import java.util.Scanner;
// imported scanner
public class fracCalc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userInput = "there is a problem";
        boolean stop = false;
        // declering variables
        while (stop == false){
            System.out.println("Enter:");
            userInput = console.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            // asks the user to type somthing and changes it to lower case and stores it in 
            // a variable
                if (userInput.equals("quit")) {
                stop = true;
                System.out.println("Thanks for using, Bye!");
                // if stop is true thenn the program stops.
                } else { 
                System.out.print(userInput + " = ");
                Scanner userInputCutter = new Scanner(userInput);
                String num1 = userInputCutter.next();
                String operator = userInputCutter.next();
                String num2 = userInputCutter.next();
                convterMethod(num1);
                convterMethod(num2);
                System.out.println(num1 + " " + operator + " " + num2);
                // this segment of code takes the user input and  cuts it up at the spaces 
                // then it sends down the first 2 operators to the converter to change them
                // to fractions or whatever there supposed to be.
            }
        }
    }
        public static String convterMethod(String token) {
        if (token.contains("_")) {
            int underScore = token.indexOf("_");
            int slash = token.indexOf("/");
            // This if statment says if it contains an _ then it will take the mixed number 
            // and convert it into a fraction
            String strWholeNumber = token.substring(0,underScore);
            String strNumerator = token.substring(underScore + 1,slash);
            String strDenomonator = token.substring(slash + 1,token.length());
            int numWholeNumber = Integer.parseInt(strWholeNumber);
            int numNumerator = Integer.parseInt(strWholeNumber);
            int numDenomonator = Integer.parseInt(strDenomonator);
            String mixedNumber = (numWholeNumber * numDenomonator + numNumerator) + "/" + strDenomonator;
            return mixedNumber;
        } else if (token.contains("/")) {
            return token;
            // if a token contains a / and nothing else its all good to go.
        } 
        token = token + "" + "/1";
        return token;
        // if a token contains neither a / or an _ then it turns into a fraction
    }
}
```

I've tried searching up this problem online and changing out things in my code. Nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns just fine. But you're ignoring the return value.

```
convterMethod(num1);
```

This takes `num1`, does a bunch of nice, neat work on it, and then.... throws away the result. It does *not* modify `num1`. If you want the result of the function to be assigned back into the `num1` variable, you need to tell Java to do so.

```
num1 = convterMethod(num1);
```

(and the same for the other places you call this function)